# Align textbox vertically on a chart in an excel workseet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a textbox box in my excel worksheet and I want to align it vertically along a chart in worksheet. I am unable to do this. Can someone help me? 
I have recorded this code using Macro recording but it does not works when I run this code. If someone has any idea, kindly guide me

```
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementRotation 90
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Textbox 1", "Chart 1")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Textbox 1").Align msoAlignTops, msoFalse
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Textbox 1").Align msoAlignRights, msoFalse
```

Comment: Should this be done in code at all? 
If so --> SO is not a coding service. 
Please provide what code you have so far and elaborate on where you got stuck.

Comment: Rik, I have edited my post. so, if you find some error or have some suggestion, please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .align method applies to a ShapeRange object, as documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744992.aspx
The macro recorder does not properly record the range of shapes, but only takes the latest selected shape into account. Since there's only 1 shape in the ShapeRange object, it cannot align it to anything else.

The following code fixes that issue, by ensuring you have both your textbox and your chart in your ShapeRange object:

```
Sub Test()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBoxNameHere", "ChartNameHere")).
        .Align msoAlignRights, msoFalse
        .Align msoAlignTops, msoFalse
    End With
End Sub
```

You might want to alter the procedure to take parameters for the TextBoxNameHere and ChartNameHere from a selection for example, so you can run the macro on any selection of a chart + a textbox. I suggest reading up on VBA programming in the first place to see how to do this. 
Some great resources for a starting point are http://www.ozgrid.com/ and http://www.rondebruin.nl/

Comment: Thank you for your help Rik :)